# How do I check if object exist in pony orm cache?

Tags: python-3.6, ponyorm

I am trying some data processing and then insert in one go, tables have some composite keys which I use to check if the record for that Id exists then it should update the record instead of creating.

While data processing there is a chance that same id exists in sample data multiple times and while processing it won't find record matching to that Id in db hence it tries to create the record everytime.

Is there any way I can check cache for composite key match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`get`](https://docs.ponyorm.com/working_with_entity_instances.html#getting-one-object-by-unique-combination-of-attributes) method of entity instance to find an object by combination of primary key values.

The `get` method searches both `db_session` cache and database, and returns `None` if no object was found:

```
from pony import orm

db = orm.Database('sqlite', ':memory:')

class Point(db.Entity):
    x = orm.Required(int)
    y = orm.Required(int)
    description = orm.Optional(str)
    orm.PrimaryKey(x, y)

db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

points = [(1, 2, 'foo'), (3, 4, 'bar'), (1, 2, 'baz'), (5, 6, 'qux')]

with orm.db_session:
    for a, b, s in points:
        point = Point.get(x=a, y=b)
        if point is None:
            point = Point(x=a, y=b, description=s)
```

The `get` method also works with secondary [composite keys](https://docs.ponyorm.com/entities.html?highlight=composite_key#composite-keys).

Also you can search for an entity instance using [square brackets](https://docs.ponyorm.com/working_with_entity_instances.html#getting-an-object-by-primary-key) and catch an exception:

```
with orm.db_session:
    try:
        point = Point[10, 20]
    except orm.ObjectNotFound:
        point = Point(x=10, y=20)
```

#### Update: clarification about IdentityMap patern usage

PonyORM uses IdentityMap design pattern. That means that all objects of the same class loaded or created inside a `db_session` are indexed by its primary key values. It is not possible multiple objects of the same class with the same primary key inside the same `db_session`. If the `get` method is called several times with the same primary key value, it will return the same instance:

```
with db_session:
    a = Point.get(x=10, y=20)
    b = Point.get(x=10, y=20)
    assert a is b  # the same object!
```

The same applied to situation when you just create an object and then attempts to `get` object with the same primary key: Pony will return the object that you just created:

```
with db_session:
    a = Point.get(x=10, y=20)
    if a is None:
        a = Point(x=10, y=20)

    # later, in the same db_session:
    b = Point.get(x=10, y=20)
    assert a is b  # the same object, not saved yet
```

On the other side, if you attempts to create two different objects with the same primary key, you will receive an error:

```
with db_session:
    a = Point(x=10, y=20)
    b = Point(x=10, y=20)

Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
pony.orm.core.CacheIndexError: Cannot create Point: instance with primary key 10, 20 already exists
```

Also, if you attempt to create an object which already exists in the database without checking it, you will get an error:

```
with db_session:
    a = Point(x=30, y=40)

with db_session:
    b = Point(x=30, y=40)

Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
pony.orm.core.TransactionIntegrityError: Object Point[30, 40] cannot be stored in the database. IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: Point.x, Point.y
```

In order to avoid this error, you can check for object existense using `get` before creating a new one.

Comment: If there is one record in database, and first set of data updated the record, now its  in cache and when second set does `get` wont it throw `MultipleObjectsFound` exception?

Comment: I updated the answer with clarification about IdentityMap pattern usage